# Does ExtJS automatically garbage collect components

Tags: javascript, extjs, garbage-collection

Imagine the following case, where I have the following HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>... include all the js and css here...</head>
    <body>
        <div class="placeholderForExtPanel"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now somewhere in my code, I tell ExtJS to render a panel in my placeholder.

```
var container = Ext.select('.placeholderForExtPanel');
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'My Panel'
});
```

A bit later, some other part of the code decides to remove the placeholder div from the DOM.

```
Ext.select('.placeholderForExtPanel').first().remove();
```

In this case, what happens to the Panel that was declared before? Do I need to manually destroy it, or does ExtJS know that it's containing element was just removed from the DOM and it should destroy the Panel by itself? I'm using ExtJS 4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtJS will not destroy components automatically if you remove the containing element. The element will be removed from the DOM, but the panel keeps its reference to it. Try the following:

```
Ext.select('.placeholderForExtPanel').first().remove();
console.log(Ext.getCmp('panel-id').getEl().dom.parentNode); // assuming your panel's id is "panel-id"
```

The element still exists, and you could just append it to the DOM again if you wanted to:

```
document.body.appendChild(Ext.getCmp('panel-id').getEl().dom.parentNode);
```

(Side note: the fact that the panel keeps the reference to it's containing element also prevents the browser's garbage collector from destroying it)

Basically it works the other way around, the component manages its corresponding DOM elements, so when you destroy the component the DOM elements will be removed as well.

Furthermore, any components which can contain other components (i.e. [Ext.container.Container](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container) and all of its subclasses) will destroy any of their child components when they are destroyed (assuming [autoDestroy](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-autoDestroy) is enabled, which is the default).

So, if you want to automatically destroy all components which have been rendered to a certain element, just create that element as a container and you should be good:

```
var container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    cls: 'placeholderForExtPanel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'mypanel'
    }]
});

container.destroy(); // destroys the container AND the panel
```

Comment: Actually, the reson I'm asking is because I want to have a ext.tree.Panel arranged as a TreeGrid that allows certain rows to render arbitrary components inside of their associated `<tr>`. This means I'm instantiating components and rendering them to that `<tr>` unforetunately, the Tree grid does not seem to send events when it decides that it needs to add or remove those `<tr>` from the `<table>`, which prevents me from catching this event and destroy the component. So I was kind of hoping things would happen automatically. Do you have an idea of what I could do?

Comment: I tried using the RowBody feature, or the RowExpander plugin, but both of them are hopelessly buggy with a tree grid.

Comment: You could listen to the [refresh](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.View-event-refresh) event on the view, as this will be fired whenever the grid view rebuilds the HTML structure. For what it's worth, rendering components to grid rows or cells is usually bad idea (I've been there too :)) as the view can refresh frequently (e.g. on sorting) and potentially a lot of components need to get rendered, which will slow down performance significantly.

Comment: I've just caught the itemadd and itemremove events. These seem to let me do what I need cleanly.